# Using external parameter in Mysql Database query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to use variable value in a query but for something not often happens  like that:

```
$sql ="select a from x where b ='".$_SESSION["b"]."' Limit '".$_GET["l"]."',1;";
```

How to set the input of `limit` properly because it seems to me not working unless there is `=` before the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query will generate

```
Limit '5',1
```

Which is invalid SQL, it has to generate

```
Limit 5,1
```

Go Figure. And Oh [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Remove '' from the sentence, `Limit ".$_GET["l"].",1;"` The use of limit in MySQL is this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sessionvar = $_SESSION['b'];
$limit = $_GET['1'];

$sql ="select a from x where b = $sessionvar Limit $limit ,1";
```